# AWS iot core data logging error using sim7600G

Tags: amazon-web-services, arduino, esp32

I got following response when i try to log data to aws iot core using esp32 on Arduino ide serial monitor. this same code was working fine yestuerday. connection is establish all is workking fine until AT+CMQTTPLAYLOAD command.

```
   AT+CMQTTSTART

   +CMQTTSTART: 0

   OK
   AT+CMQTTACCQ=0,"bin",1

   OK
   AT+CMQTTWILLTOPIC=0,31

   >aws/things/simcom7600_device01/
   OK
   AT+CMQTTWILLMSG=0,17,1

   >SIMCom Connected!
   OK
   AT+CMQTTCONNECT=0,"tcp://a37y687a72t5ev-ats.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:8883",60,1

   OK

   AT+CMQTTPAYLOAD=0,38

   >{"message":"Hello from SIMCom Module"}
   OK
   AT+CMQTTPUB=0,1,60

   OK  
   +CMQTTPUB: 0,0

   +CMQTTRXSTART: 0,31,38
   +CMQTTRXTOPIC: 0,31
   aws/things/simcom7600_device01/
   +CMQTTRXPAYLOAD: 0,38
   {"message":"Hello from SIMCom Module"}
   +CMQTTRXEND: 0
   AT+CMQTTDISC=0,120



   +CMQTTDISC: 0,0
```